# How do I stop Eclipse XML formatter putting text on new lines?

Tags: xml, eclipse, code-formatting

I have some XML that looks like this (after pasting a new Maven dependency):

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>3.6.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
<groupId>net.sourceforge.jtds</groupId>
<artifactId>jtds</artifactId>
<version>1.3.0</version>
</dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.11</version>
    </dependency>
```

When I select the text and select *Source → Format* (Ctrl+Shift+F by default), I expect it to end up looking like this:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>3.6.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sourceforge.jtds</groupId>
        <artifactId>jtds</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.11</version>
    </dependency>
```

But instead, it looks like this:

```
    </dependency><dependency>

        <groupId>
org.hibernate
        </groupId>

        <artifactId>
hibernate-entitymanager
        </artifactId>

        <version>
3.6.0.Final
        </version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>

        <groupId>
net.sourceforge.jtds
        </groupId>

        <artifactId>
jtds
        </artifactId>

        <version>
1.3.0
        </version>
```

Yuck!

If I don't select any text and try to just format the entire file, it does the same thing: put newline characters before all text (character data).

I've played with settings in *Window → Preferences → XML → XML Files → Editor → Formatting*, but none of them seem to fix this. There's certainly no 'Insert annoying newline characters before text' checkbox ticked!

Any ideas for how to fix this? FWIW, formatting Java code works beautifully.

*Help → About Eclipse*:

```
Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers.

Version: Indigo Service Release 2
Build id: 20120216-1857
```

I'm launching Eclipse for Windows from within Cygwin, but not noticing any other CR/LF-related issues. Still, I tried switching the file from unix- to DOS-style linefeeds, but that made no difference.

Comment: It might help to identify which editor you're using to do the formatting.  Check the file's "Open With" context menu to see which one you're using.

Comment: That steered me in the right direction! The context menu didn't tell me specifically which editor I was using, but I realised I've gotten so used to clicking past the Android editor's specialised tab that it didn't even occur to me. If you post 'check that you're really using the XML editor' as an answer, I'll give it the credit it deserves. Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check that you're using the XML Editor; you're using its preference page and those preferences may not applicable to other editors.

Comment: Turns out I was using the Android editor, and putting newlines before text is a standard for Android code.

Comment: I am using xml editor, but when I format the file, it will put the close tag in new line. hot to avoid it?

Answer (score 7):

I was experiencing these issue due to the **line width** setting under ***XML > XML Files > Editor***. Increased to 200 and the line breaks went away. [image]

Note: Some developers might discourage you from increasing this to +80 incase your code is ever printed or viewed on a mobile device. It is also good to keep in mind, side-by-side and three-way code compare tools. In this situation, increasing the line width setting could make legibility difficult.

Edited thanks to @MichaelScheper 's comment

Comment: Line width is one of those issues devs often fight about. I respect devs who prefer the standard 80, simply so they have room for size-by-side diffs (including three-way diffs, when resolving merging conflicts). In most languages, including XML, using double-indents for line continuation makes lines perfectly readable, and having code that stretches entirely across the screen is hard to read anyhow. (Notice how StackOverflow has such wide ← margins →? It's for the same reason.)

Comment: Great point about the side-by-side and three-way diffs. I overlooked those situations where it most defiantly is beneficial.

Comment: Yes, I've been accused of being 'defiant' about this, numerous times.  Thanks for considering my experience.